# Core Data Light Weight Migration without being killed on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

Our app requires a Core Data lightweight migration, as we have added a few attributes to our entities.

After releasing the update to our beta testers on TestFlight we had reports from some of them that the app was crashing on launch. After getting crash logs we realized that the springboard watchdog was killing the app because the migration was taking too long.

After scouring resources online, it seems that it is possible to offload the migration outside of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` by first checking to see if a migration is needed, not touching the Core Data stack, and choosing to do the migration in another view controller. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[ZSSCoreDataManager sharedService] migrationRequired]) {

        UpgradeDatabaseViewController *upgrade = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UpgradeDatabaseViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = upgrade;

    }

    return YES;

}
```

Migration test:

```
- (BOOL)migrationRequired {

    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataMergeTest.sqlite"];

    // Determine if a migration is needed
    NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];
    NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectModel];
    BOOL pscCompatibile = [destinationModel isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

    return !pscCompatibile;

}
```

UpgradeDatabaseViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Starting migration");

    // Start migration by accessing th epersistent container
    [[ZSSCoreDataManager sharedService] persistentContainer];

    NSLog(@"Ended migration");

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNav"];
    window.rootViewController = nav;

}
```

Persistent Container:

```
- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {

    @synchronized (self) {

        if (_persistentContainer != nil) {
            return _persistentContainer;
        }

        _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"Model"];

        // Store description
        NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataMergeTest.sqlite"];
        NSPersistentStoreDescription *description = [NSPersistentStoreDescription persistentStoreDescriptionWithURL:storeURL];

        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = YES;
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = YES;

        description.type = NSSQLiteStoreType;
        _persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = @[description];

        [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error){
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                //abort();
            }
        }];

        _persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
        _persistentContainer.viewContext.undoManager = nil; // We don't need undo so set it to nil.
        _persistentContainer.viewContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = YES;
        _persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;

    }

    return _persistentContainer;

}
```

Sadly this still doesn't seem to solve the issue as springboard will still kill the app (when device is not plugged in and debugger is running).

**Is there something here that I have done wrong? Does the lightweight migration happen in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` regardless of whether we don't init our database?**

**Is it even possible to do what I am wanting to do while using lightweight migration?**

Answer (score 2):

Migration happens when you load the persistent store. With `NSPersistentContainer`, it happens whenever you call `loadPersistentStores()`. In your code it looks like that's probably in `ZSSCoreDataManager`'s `persistentContainer` method.

It's not about what *method* you do this on, it's a question of what *queue* you call it on. The watchdog will kill your app if you block the main queue for a long time. When you do that, your app has stopped responding. Watchdog can't tell why that happens, and the rule it enforces is to treat this as a hung process and kill it. This is generally a good idea because it only happens when your app has been sitting there ignoring user input for a long time. If you handle migration in a `viewDidLoad`, you're on the main queue, which is why your app gets killed.

I'm not sure if this can be fixed with just `NSPersistentContainer`. That class is designed to handle the most common situations, but you seem to be outside that. In the past what I've done is use `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to load the persistent store on a background queue, then created whatever managed object contexts I need. You might be able to deal with this by first using `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to handle migration, and then loading the `NSPersistentContainer` when it finishes.

Fixing this will depend in part on whether you can reproduce the crash. If you can't do that now, that's probably the first step-- get to where you're seeing the same crash as your users, so that you can tell when that crash is fixed.

Comment: I have updated my question to show how my `NSPersistentContainer` is created. This is all I am using to init my `Core Data` stack since our app is iOS 10. Are you saying that I could do the creation of my `NSPersistentContainer` object on a background queue?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the crash that my users have. A user provided me their .sqlite file. I never saw the crash since my device was connected to the debugger and the watchdog process isn't running.

Comment: @NicHubbard My answer already covers details of how and when you should set up your persistent container. Is there something specific about it that's not clear?

Comment: I was able to move the creation of my NSPersistentContainer to a background thread and it let the app load, show my migration UI and everything migrated correctly. Is NSPersistentContainer thread safe?